# connect woo rest api to a live server wp multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to this, i want to configure the woo custom dashboad and was following https://www.cloudways.com/blog/custom-dashboard-using-woocommerce-php-rest-api/.

following the basic setup,

i'm on ftp testing this but i get is a blank page,how will i do to connect to the rest api and another thing my intention is to use this for a wp multisite, will work for me?

```
   <?php



  $woocommerce = new Client('https://myscustom.com/',
                     'ck_testclient numbers',
                     'cs_testid1',
                     [
                     'wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3',
  ]);

 var_dump($woocommerce);
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

as far the api connection on a life server i had to many issues with composer by it self so i did it without it, now is connecting. make sure to get the right path

this was found at https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php/issues/146

```
<?php

   require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/Client.php');
     require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/BasicAuth.php');
       require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php');
    require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClientException.php');
    require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/OAuth.php');
  require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/Options.php');
   require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/Request.php');
  require_once(__DIR__.'/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/Response.php');

  use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
  use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

     $woocommerce = new Client('https://ursite.com/',
                     'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',

      [
        'wp_api' => true, 'version' => 'wc/v3',

      ]);
  ?>
```